# Kafka track consumer progress

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have one Kafka topic and four consumer groups.   In each group there can be different numbers of nodes consuming.   Different groups can consume at different rates and some can fall behind, but I want to know if this happens and how far behind.  I want to track how far each group is in consuming the topic.  Can I get the offset in each consumer and write that to metrics.   Or will the offset not be a great indication as it may be different across partitions and I need to do something different.   By the way there will be quite a few partitions.

There are other things I can do but would rather not change the payload to add a counter or timestamp if there is an easier way?

Thanks.

Comment: As of Kafka 0.10.2, all records already have a timestamp, by the way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to measure what's known as **consumer lag**.  There's several way to get this information, including (but not limited) to:

- External service that monitors and you can query directly - https://github.com/linkedin/Burrow
- There's included command line utilities with Kafka that can show this information.  Specifically, **kafka-consumer.groups.sh** has an `--offsets` option that will show the latest topics as well as the consumer lag.
- You can programatically query Kafka to get the latest offsets, as well as latest consumed offsets per consumer group.

Comment: I need the consumer lag to be per consumer group then report which group has fallen behind.  I am familiar with consumer lag but I did not think it was able to tell me which group had fallen behind?

Comment: You wrote "You can programatically query Kafka to get the latest offsets, as well as latest consumed offsets per consumer group."    This seems like what I want but will comparing the different offsets across consumer groups be a good guide to know if a consumer group has fallen behind?   In other words is the offset on the same topic across different partitions the same when the same record is being consumed?

Comment: @mrmannione on your last question, yes, the offsets on the same topic/partition, across different consumer groups, are exactly the same.  The offset is the actual message number stored in kafka per partition/topic, so that stays the same regardless of who is consuming it.

Comment: Assuming a Java consumer, you can also enable JMX and look at lag metrics there

Answer (score 0):

For 0.9 (and higher) consumer APIs:

```
./bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --group count_errors --describe
GROUP                          TOPIC                          PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             OWNER
count_errors                   logs                           2          2908278         2908278         0               consumer-1_/10.8.0.55
count_errors                   logs                           3          2907501         2907501         0               consumer-1_/10.8.0.43
count_errors                   logs                           4          2907541         2907541         0               consumer-1_/10.8.0.177
count_errors                   logs                           1          2907499         2907499         0               consumer-1_/10.8.0.115
count_errors                   logs                           0          2907469         2907469         0               consumer-1_/10.8.0.126
```

Older:

```
# ./bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.ConsumerOffsetChecker --broker-info --group test_group --topic test_topic --zookeeper localhost:2181
Group           Topic                  Pid Offset          logSize         Lag             Owner
test_group      test_topic             0   698020          698021          1              test_group-0
test_group      test_topic             1   235699          235699          0               test_group-1
test_group      test_topic             2   117189          117189          0               test_group-2
```

source: [SO - What command shows all of the topics and offsets of partitions in Kafka?](https://What%20command%20shows%20all%20of%20the%20topics%20and%20offsets%20of%20partitions%20in%20Kafka?)